# java generic casting in generic classes

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm writing a simple implementation of a generic max heap. If I write

```
public class FastMaxHeap<T>{

  T[] data;
  int size;

  static final int HEAP_SIZE = 10000;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public FastMaxHeap(){
    data = (T[]) new Object[HEAP_SIZE];
  size = 0;
  }
}
```

it compiles. Now to actually implement the heap, i.e. write maxHeapify(), I need to be able to compare two T's. One option that a priori seems possible would be to tell the compiler that T implements Comparable. But if I type replace < T > with < T implements Comparable > the compiler complains -- how can I do this?

Alternatively, I could define a class

```
public class HasValue{

  int value;

  public HasValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
  }
```

}

and in theory I should then be able to compare two HasValue objects like x.value > y.value. But if I type

```
public class FastMaxHeap<T extends HasValue>{

  T[] data;
  int size;

  static final int HEAP_SIZE = 10000;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public FastMaxHeap(){
    data = (T[]) new Object[HEAP_SIZE];
  size = 0;
  }
}
```

I now get a ClassCastException. What is going on here? Java generics hurt my brain.

Comment: Why not just store `Comparables`?

Comment: +1 for "Java generics hurt my brain."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case `T extends Object` which is erased to `Object` at runtime.

In the second case `T extends HasValue` is erased to `HasValue` so you need to have.

```
data = (T[]) new HasValue[HEAP_SIZE];
```

IMHO It is needlessly pedantic that Java doesn't allow `new T[HEAP_SIZE]` to do what you have to do anyway.

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: @stefanbachert The casting will work provided the component type of the new array is a sub-type of what T extends.

Comment: It's not "needlessly pedantic"; it's very important. Try to return `data` from a method in your class with return type `T[]` and see what happens.

Comment: @newacct Can you be more specific?

Comment: I am assuming you mean you want Java to allow `new T[HEAP_SIZE]` to mean `(T[])new HasValue[HEAP_SIZE];`. But that is unsafe so it is important to force the user to have to explicitly override it.

Comment: @newacct I am sure that makes sense to a degree but if *very* few people understand the distinction I suspect you haven't gained anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one (not compiled, yet)

```
public class FastMaxHeap<T extends HasValue>{

  HasValue[] data;
  int size;

  static final int HEAP_SIZE = 10000;

   public FastMaxHeap(){
     data = new HasValue[HEAP_SIZE];
     size = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you drop the casting you don't need the suppress warning

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have type token to create arrays like this

```
public class FastMaxHeap<T>{

  T[] data;
  int size;

  static final int HEAP_SIZE = 10000;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public FastMaxHeap(Class<T> clazz){
    data = (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, HEAP_SIZE);
    size = 0;
  }
}
```

In such way you will have no ClassCastExceptions in runtime

And also: `< T implements Comparable >` is not correct, correct one is `< T extends Comparable >`

Answer (score 0):

Your heap should accept a Comparator< T > as a constructor argument.  Problem solved.  Client can use any type he wants.  You can also supply a simple overload which infers the comparator implementation for types T that already implement Comparable.