# java trim generic array

Tags: java, generics, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating generic arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013683/creating-generic-arrays-in-java)

I want to trim a generic array of objects down to only the first len elements. This seems like it should work:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] trimArray(T[] data, int len){
    T[] result = (T[]) new Object[len];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, result, 0, len);
    return result;
}
```

But it throws a ClassCastException if I do something like

```
public class Foo{

    double f;

    public Foo(double f){
    this.f = f;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Foo[] A = new Foo[10];
    A[0]= new Foo(1);
    A[1]= new Foo(2);
    A[2]= new Foo(3);
    Foo[] B = trimArray(A, 3);

}
```

I don't understand why this won't work, but something similar does in [java generic casting in generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960601/java-generic-casting-in-generic-classes)

Comment: Post the full StackTrace.

Comment: a `Foo[]` array is not the same thing as an `Object[]`: you can store anything you want in the second one, whereas you can only store Foo instances in the first one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JDK already has a builtin for this:

```
Foo[] B = Arrays.copyOf(A, 3);
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) (since 1.6)

Note however that it will also *expand* the array (padded with `null`s) if the source array length is less than the wanted length. You can easily work around this by using, for instance:

```
Foo[] B = Arrays.copyOf(A, Math.min(3, A.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Arrays are covariant, meaning you can treat an Array of a subtype freely as an array of the supertype, but the opposite isn't true.

What you *can* do, although it's an ugly hack, is return an `Object[]` and then cast each element to `T` (the actual elements in the array are covariant, but the array itself is not), as needed, but I would *strongly* advise against it.

Use the builtins recommended in another answers, like `Arrays.copyOf`.

In case you're wondering *why*, it's because this would break type safety too easily.

For instance:

```
Object[] bla = new Object[10];
bla[0] = new Integer(2);
bla[1] = "stillanObject";
```

You have an array of objects, perfectly valid.

Now you cast it to, say, an array of strings...

```
return (String[])bla;
```

And hell would be unleashed upon the JVM, you would actually have an Array that should be of type `String` containing `String` and `Integer` objects! \

Type safety is a good thing.

UPDATE:

Just to add one more detail, you can cast `String[]` to `Object[]`, but this may incur in an `ArrayStoreException` if you try to store anything that is not a `String` (or type of original array). Reading the original array as `Object[]` is perfectly safe though.

Comment: From WP: "covariant: converting from a specialized type (Cats) to a more general type (Animals): Every cat is an animal." Now, you convert from more general (Object) to more special (String). And call it covariant. Are you sure?

Comment: You're right, I switched up terms there, should be fixed.